# Firestore update list of object

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use Firestore.

I have a collection **Group** which contains a List of users

```
    public class User {

    private String mail;
    private String username;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String mail, String username) {
        this.mail = mail;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}
```

I would like to update this list so I've tried :

```
List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new User("mail@gmail.com", "foo"));
        reference.update("users", list)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
                    }
                });
    }
```

But I have an exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: my.package.name.models.User

How can I update a list of object using Firestore ?

Comment: You can't perform list operations on an array field in Firestore (in any language).  You have to read the array, modify it locally, then write the array back out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#update(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) update doesn't accept `List`.

Also, [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) here that you can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of `set()`, `update()`, or `delete()` operations, using the `WriteBatch`.